# EHCache 3 not working as a Map

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, ehcache

I'm using EHCache for my Spring application and I don't think its working as expected

If you see below I'm adding the same data to a hashmap and also to Ehcache .. but when I tried to get it from the ehCache it prints null

Is there anything wrong in the way I have initialized the Cache or something that I have missed.

My class

```
@Named
public class Myclass extends DataLoader {
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Myclass.class.getName());
@Inject
private DictionaryInitializer dictionaryLoader;

@Inject
@Named("fileLoader")
private FileLoader fileLoader;

private Cache<String,Object> dictionary;

@PostConstruct
@Override
public void loadResource() {
    List<String> spellTerms = null;
    dictionary=dictionaryLoader.getCache();
    String fileName = "C:\\spelling.txt";
    spellTerms = fileLoader.loadResource(fileName);     
    HashMap<String,Object> dictData = new HashMap<>();
    for(String line:spellTerms) 
    {           
        for (String key : parseWords(line))
        {
            HashMap<String,Object> tempMap =  dictionaryUtil.indexWord(key);

            if(tempMap!=null && !tempMap.isEmpty())
            {
            Set<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entries = tempMap.entrySet();
            for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry:entries)
            {
                dictionary.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
            }
            dictData.putAll(tempMap);

        }
    }
    System.out.println(dictData.get("urcle"));  //prints 45670  
    System.out.println(dictionary.get("urcle")); // prints null


}       

private static Iterable<String> parseWords(String text)
{
    List<String> allMatches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[\\w-[\\d_]]+").matcher(text.toLowerCase());
    while (m.find()) {
        allMatches.add(m.group());
    }
    return allMatches;
}

}
```

My DictionaryInitializer is like below

```
public class DictionaryInitializer {
private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(DictionaryInitializer.class.getName());
private Cache<String,Object> dictionary;
@PostConstruct
public void initializeCache() {
    CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManagerBuilder.newCacheManagerBuilder()      

            .build(true);
    this.dictionary = cacheManager.createCache("myCache",
            CacheConfigurationBuilder.newCacheConfigurationBuilder(String.class, Object.class,
                    ResourcePoolsBuilder.heap(100)).build());
    LOGGER.info("Dictionary loaded");
}
public Cache<String,Object> getCache(){
    return dictionary;
}
public void setCache(Cache<String,Object> dictionary) {
    this.dictionary=dictionary;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.

I have initialized the Cache with a heap of just 100 entry and hence it takes only the fist 100 entries into the cache.

Fixed that and it works as expected

Comment: héhé ! be careful with cache sizing !

Comment: Watch out. A cache is not a map. If you are reading data that should persist in memory for ever after, that's not a cache you want. A cache might evict and return null when it feels like it (even if the actual implementation won't do it in general). So if you want to just keep data on heap, you want a map.